# Redirect /download URI to subdomain on same domain

Tags: php, nginx, server-administration

I finished developed an app that features a downloading system that is hosted with NGINX at:

http://dashboard.myapp.com

The URL for downloads is:

http://dashboard.myapp.com/download/file-slug

This page is a regular PHP page that will require some user input and then PHP handles the actual file download, it's not the direct path for the file.

Since these download URLs will be made publicly available, I want to ditch that dashboard subdomain.

The default domain (myapp.com) is already working with a wordpress setup with this:

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
```

Is there an easy way to get the:

http://myapp.com/download/file-slug

to act as if:

http://dashboard.myapp.com/download/file-slug

was accessed, without actually redirecting?

Comment: "To act as if..." - Please explain what you mean. Do you want to continue to use the subdomain, but the user sees `myapp.com/download/file-slug`, such as if it's on a different server?

Comment: Yes, the user would then be able to access with or without the dashboard subdomain.

Comment: Are the files on the same server, and you just want the URL the user sees to not have `dashboard.myapp.com`?

Comment: Yes, the desired behaviour is not to see the dashboard.myapp.com.

Comment: However /download/file-slug is just a regular PHP page, no actual files involved, it does not trigger any download.

Comment: What happens if you copy the PHP file to `myapp.com/download/file-slug`?

Comment: I'm using a rather large PHP framework, so that is not an option, everything is included and routed accordingly from an index.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - Place in your server block for myapp.com, anywhere outside another location block. Set the root to the same root as the `dashboard` subdomain (if on the same server). The script would see itself as being hosed at `myapp.com` instead of `dashboard.myapp.com`, but it should retain the remainder of the framework rules. If this doesn't work, try the next option.

```
location /download/file-slug { 
    root /path/folder;  
    try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```

Another option is to proxy through Nginx. This option actually runs the script on the current location, accessing it like a client would through `dashboard.myapp.com`. See [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) documentation on [Nginx.org](http://www.nginx.org).

```
location /download/file-slug { proxy_pass http://dashboard.myapp.com/download/file-slug; }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the route /download/file-slug is actually for a regular PHP page that will require for some input and then the PHP handles downloading the file, so that solution wouldn't work.

Comment: I've changed the initial option a bit - Essentially it would run your code from the other subdomain as if it were on `myapp.com`. If that won't work, try the second one which just proxies to `dashboard.myapp.com`. The top one is probably a better option if it works, but really it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: I think I should explain my methodology a little bit - Using `proxy_pass` should be avoided if possible. When you use `proxy_pass` in this way, it has to run a DNS query, handle the TCP overhead, and deal with the response time of the other server. It's not a bad thing, but can increase response time. Security - Somewhat null since you declare Google's DNS, but someone could hijack your requests if they know what they are doing (very unlikely). Reliability - If the other server/instance goes down, you appear to lose your main site too.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work it out with Nginx only.

Inside the myapp.com config file I added:

```
    location ~ /download/(.*) {
            resolver 8.8.8.8; 
            proxy_pass http://dashboard.myapp.com/download/$1;
    }
```

The resolver 8.8.8.8 is actually using Google DNS. Without this line I was getting a "no resolver defined to resolve" error.

Comment: Do **NOT** use a publicly accessible DNS server such as `8.8.8.8`. [To prevent DNS spoofing, it is recommended configuring DNS servers in a properly secured trusted local network.](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver)